# Git - Merging from a PR overwrites previous commits leaving no history, why is this happening?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

We are using github, and most of us are using github desktop to manage our branches and commits. We are having an issue where commits are getting overwritten but leaving no history. Example: person A will make a change to a file in their own branch, create a PR, and get it merged into our main branch. Person B will make a different change to the same file in their own branch, create a PR, and get it merged into our main branch. The changes from person A will go missing after person B's PR merges into our main branch. Looking at the commit history will show person A made a change, and then person B made a different change, but in the history for person B, which is after person A it does not show them undoing person A's changes, but the file at that time does not contain person A's changes. We aren't sure why this is happening and not leaving any history, any one have an idea?

Edit: I made a video of the commit history of one of the issues here: vimeo.com/905744582 initially on line 45 I changed 6 to 63, the commit after mine added a line above that and you'll notice it is back to 6.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for us to answer the question. Please perform a controlled test and then update the question with the exact sequence of steps that was necessary to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @larsks I'm unsure of the exact steps that reproduces this issue because it doesn't happen all the time. The history is missing the commit that undoes the change so I can't track down what happened and I'm hoping someone might know what would cause the history to not show that a previous commit was undone

Comment: Do you merges the PRs or are you creating squash commits?

Comment: @knittl we do not do squash commits, we are merging.

Comment: @munkledata then the commits cannot get "lost/hidden". How do you verify that the commits are (not) there?

Comment: @knittl I made a video of the commit history of one of the issues here: https://vimeo.com/905744582
initially on line 45 I changed 6 to 63, the commit after mine added a line above that and you'll notice it is back to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation in my opinion is in how merge conflicts were resolved.

By default, `git show -p` won't show you the changes in a merge commit, but you can change that with `--diff-merges`.

Try

```
git show -p <sha-of-merge-commit> --diff-merges=separate
```

using the SHA of person B's merge commit.

In the output, you should see two sections each starting with `commit <merge-sha> (from <parent-sha>)`. Inspect those carefully to see if it's during the merge itself that person A's work was removed.

If so, the problem is related to how Person B actually merged that PR.

Comment: Running that command shows that it was the merge that removed it, do you know if it is possible to have github show the changes in merge commits so that we can catch this in PRs?

Comment: If you are using GitHub, why are you merging locally? GitHub doesn't let you merge if you have conflicts

Comment: @knittl the only local merge is to bring main into the branch (using github desktops "update from" menu option) so that the branch is up to date and can be merged back into main through github's web UI.

Comment: @munkledata This is a challenging question, because if person B merged main in that way, they're declaring the correct merge was to undo person A's work. But, when reviewing person B's PR, I'm surprised the Pull Request's Files Changed tab didn't show that. I would have expected it to show you the net total impact of the PR on main, including undoing person A's work.